# Mage_ImportExport: Why is the import of custom option type "file" disabled?

Tags: custom-options, importexport

In `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_saveCustomOptions` the custom option type "file" is commented out in product import. If you uncomment it and change `'image_size_x'   => 0,` to `'image_size_x'   => null,` and `'image_size_y'   => 0,` to `'image_size_y'   => null,` below (following http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/275362/), you can reenable it. I just tested it successfully and was able to import custom options of type "file".

Does anyone know why this isn't enabled by default?

Comment: I can't understand the history in JIRA so I pinged Piotr.

Comment: I don't think this will ever get an answer. Only a core dev may be able to answer it. I will close it for now. If something comes up, please vote to reopen it.